# Display connected through VGA to HDMI converter not detected in Settings -> Display, but works if any video is cast to the display

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

I am trying to connect a SONY TV as a monitor to my Ubuntu (18.04) laptop through a VGA (input) to HDMI (output) converter. But this display is not detected in Settings -> Display.

But if I select "play on TV" from youtube, the video is played on the TV screen.

Is it not possible to use a TV as a monitor? How do I use it as a mirror screen?